# mysql container linking to only one containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

This is the docker-compose.yml file

```
 mySql:
      image: mysql:latest
      environment:
         MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
  myContainer1:
      image: container1:latest
      ports:
         - 9000:9000
      links:
         - mySql:dev-mysql
  myContainer2:
      image: container2:latest
      ports:
          - 9001:9000
      links:
          - mySql:dev-mysql
          - myContainer1:dev
```

Now when i am runing this file i am getting MySql timeout error with myContainer1 but with myContainer2 it is working fine.

Error log of myContainer1:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: Timeout after
>   10001ms of waiting for a connection.
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.getConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:227)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.getConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:182)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:93)
>       at slick.jdbc.hikaricp.HikariCPJdbcDataSource.createConnection(HikariCPJdbcDataSource.scala:12)
>       at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.conn$lzycompute(JdbcBackend.scala:415)
>       at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.conn(JdbcBackend.scala:414)
>       at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$SessionDef$class.prepareStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:297)
>       at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.prepareStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:407)
>       at slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.results(StatementInvoker.scala:33)
>       at slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.iteratorTo(StatementInvoker.scala:22)
>       at slick.jdbc.Invoker$class.foreach(Invoker.scala:48)
>       at slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.foreach(StatementInvoker.scala:16)
>       at slick.jdbc.StreamingInvokerAction$class.run(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:22)
>       at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$QueryActionExtensionMethodsImpl$$anon$1.run(JdbcActionComponent.scala:218)
>       at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$QueryActionExtensionMethodsImpl$$anon$1.run(JdbcActionComponent.scala:218)
>       at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anon$2.liftedTree1$1(DatabaseComponent.scala:237)
>       at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anon$2.run(DatabaseComponent.scala:237)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Can you explain a bit what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i need to link mysql container with multiple containers but it is working with only one container and not with the other containers